# I want my bot to only recognize commands that start with a capital letter

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
exports.run = async (bot,message,args) => {
    if (!args.length) {
        return (message.channel.send('no card was requested'))
    }

    message.channel.send(`https://metazoospellbook.com/image/${args.join('%20')}KS.png`)



}

exports.help = {
    name: 'card'
```

I have this portion working fine, but I only want it to read arguments that start with a capital letter i.e. 'Bookmark" instead of 'bookmark'

Comment: Please add more code to help you easily

Comment: this is the entire code for the command

Comment: Ok. I add an answer I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

test if `message.content [ 0 ]` is the same as `message.content [ 0 ].toUpperCase ( )`

Comment: additional testing is needed, for example `"5"` is the same as `"5".toUpperCase()` but it is not an upper case "letter"

Answer (score 0):

`includes` method of string can help you if you test a string with full upercase char.

```js
const uppercases = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

console.log("isUppercase ?", uppercases.includes("a"))
console.log("isUppercase ?", uppercases.includes("A"))
```

will give you "true" if the `letter` is a uppercase.

So you can use a [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function to only take argument that start with an uppercase.

Here is a solution :

```js
const uppercases = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function checkUppercase(word) {
  return uppercases.includes(word[0])
}

function getOnlyUppercaseArgs(args) {
  return args.split(" ").filter(word => checkUppercase(word))
}

const args = "Here is My argument In lower And upper Case"

console.log(getOnlyUppercaseArgs(args))
```

Comment: okay, so i understand where you are going with the split and filter, but I'm unsure how to implement that into the code to make it work